# Asserting an array list in Javascript using testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've just started using something called testcafe. I'm looking to assert that I have received a list back with the selector '#audit > h4'. It would need to be >= 1. I'm not sure on the syntax to use for the >= 1 or where it should be placed as being new to JS.

Here's my code so far the second test is the one that requires advice:

```
fixture `UI Tests`
    .page `http://localhost:8080/`;

test('Clicking the search button', async t => {
    await t
        .click ('#search-result > div > div > button');
});

test('Asserting a list of audits', async t => {
    await t
        .expect('#audit > h4')
});
```

Comment: Try looking at the documentation here: http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html#great-than-or-equal-to

Comment: Yeah I had that open all day yesterday still didn't help me with my original question though.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer eventually

```
.expect(Selector(page.auditListId).count).gte(2);
```